# Getting instance ip from weblogic cluster

Tags: java, cluster-computing, weblogic-10.x

I have a problem on how to get an instance URL within a cluster with weblogic.

Description:
We have 2 domains: X and Y.
In each domain I have 2 clusters: c01 and c02
In each cluster I have instances: s01,s02,s03,s04
In each instances I have our system which contains of several components, let’s call the components A,B,C and D. I want to make a REST call from A to D which are still in the same instance.  How will we get the URL and port to this REST service programmatically?

The problem is that I am just getting the cluster URL when calling InetAddress or alike. I have also played around with MBean, but we are not sure it’s correct way to go since I wont have any user/pass to fill in for Enviroment object when creating the context.

We don’t want this as a build property since we don’t want to do builds for each different instance.

Env:
SpringIntegration
Weblogic 10.3.3
Jersey
Maven

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Got it from an RuntimeServiceMBean:

```
service = new ObjectName(
                "com.bea:Name=RuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.RuntimeServiceMBean");

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        MBeanServer mBeanServer = (MBeanServer) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime");

        ObjectName rt = (ObjectName) mBeanServer.getAttribute(service, "ServerRuntime");
        listenAddress = (String) mBeanServer.getAttribute(rt, "ListenAddress");
        server = listenAddress.substring(0, listenAddress.indexOf("/"));
        port = (Integer)mBeanServer.getAttribute(rt, "ListenPort");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.
I have a question though: Does it work wth WLS 12c?